# How to speed up my webscraping python code?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, finance

I've been working on Python code to pull data from stock-trading simulation software (I get the tickers for the securities I'm trading, e.g. VTI, AAPL, GOOG, etc.), then search Morningstar for the ticker and pull pricing info and whatever else I want from that site.  I save the data I want from lists into a .csv file for use in Excel.  I'm using Selenium to run a webdriver (I use either Chrome to see the process visually or PhantomJS to run the program headless without browser GUI), and beautifulsoup to access the websites and work with the HTML.

I have the program working decently, but it takes upwards of 120 seconds to run through a portfolio of only 11 securities, and I am hoping to expand this program to do more elaborate actions.

Is there anything in my coding style that could be changed to speed up the webscraping process?  Are there any general methods of writing Python code to allow for fast execution?

Here's the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

#browser = webdriver.Chrome() #replace with .Firefox(), or with the browser of your choice
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()

security_links_list = list()
equitysim_ticker_list = list()

url = ['https://www.equitysim.com/Home'
]

for item in url:

 browser.get(item) #navigate to page behind login
 username = browser.find_element_by_id('placeholderContent_txtUserName')
 username.send_keys('EDITED_FOR_SECURITY')
 password = browser.find_element_by_id('placeholderContent_txtPassword')
 password.send_keys('EDITED_FOR_SECURITY')
 form = browser.find_element_by_id("placeholderContent_LoginButton")
 form.click()

 innerHTML = browser.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML") #returns the inner HTML as a string
 innerHTML = browser.page_source
 html = browser.page_source
 soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
 table_a = soup.find('table', 'ba-tbl admintable')
 for a in table_a.find_all('a', href=True):
    security_links_list.append(a['href'])
links_set = set(security_links_list)
links_set.remove('#')
print(links_set)

mystring = "https://www.equitysim.com"

links_set_revised = [mystring + link_text for link_text in links_set]
print(links_set_revised)

for item in links_set_revised:

 browser.get(item)
 innerHTML = browser.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML") #returns the inner HTML as a string
 innerHTML = browser.page_source
 html = browser.page_source
 soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

 title_element = soup.find("title")
 title = title_element.text
 ticker = title.split(':', 1)[0]

 ticker = ticker.replace('\n','')
 ticker = ticker.replace('\t','')

 equitysim_ticker_list.append(ticker)

print(equitysim_ticker_list)

morningstar_ticker_search = "http://quote.morningstar.com/TickerLookup.html"
uri_links = list()

for ticker in equitysim_ticker_list:
 browser.get(morningstar_ticker_search)
 enter_ticker = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Ticker']")
 enter_ticker.click()
 search_ticker = browser.find_element_by_class_name('F3')
 search_ticker.send_keys(ticker)
 go_box = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@src='http://im.morningstar.com/im/go.gif']")
 go_box.click()

 html = browser.page_source
 soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
 outer_div = soup.find('div', attrs={'id': 'quote_quicktake'})
 iframe = outer_div.find('iframe').get('src')
 full_url = 'https:' + iframe
 uri_links.append(full_url)

print(uri_links)

price_list = list()
ticker_list = list()
nav_list = list()

for item in uri_links:

 browser.get(item) #navigate to page behind login
 innerHTML = browser.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML") #returns the inner HTML as a string
 innerHTML = browser.page_source
 html = browser.page_source
 soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

 price_element = soup.find("div", attrs={"id": "lastPrice"})
 price = price_element.text # strip() is used to remove starting and trailing

 nav_element = soup.find("span", attrs={"id": "NAV"} or {"vkey": "NAV"})
 nav = nav_element.text
 nav_split1 = nav.split('\n                                   \t\t', 1)[1]
 nav_split2 = nav_split1.split(' ', 1)[0]

 title_element = soup.find("title")
 title = title_element.text
 ticker = title.split(' ', 1)[0]

 price_list.append(price)
 nav_list.append(nav_split2)
 ticker_list.append(ticker)

 print(ticker)
 print(price)
 print(nav_split2)
 #ticker =

print(ticker_list)
print(price_list)
print(nav_list)


csvfile = "C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\personal\\exampleCsv.csv"

#Assuming res is a flat list
with open(csvfile, "w") as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output,lineterminator='')
    writer.writerow(ticker_list)
    writer.writerow('\n')
    writer.writerow(price_list)
    writer.writerow('\n')
    writer.writerow(nav_list)
```

Comment: Fair question, but this is a little off-topic for StackOverflow, as there could be many different correct answers to this problem.

Comment: The canonical response to this question is to run more browsers in parallel, often done using some kind of queue like celery. Put all URLs in a queue, then span as much workers as your hardware/network can handle in order to fetch them. If you don't need javascript, consider scrapy or robot.

Comment: To speed up webscraping, do **not** use Selenium. Use an http library to fetch pages, and parse them using an XML library.

Comment: @SiKing I looked into your suggestion a bit and read that Beautifulsoup's parser could be swapped with lxml parser.  Is this what you mean by parsing with an XML library?  Also, as to your suggestion to fetching pages with an http library, are you referring to using a library such as Requests?  I'll look into this for myself tomorrow as well, but any direct suggestion would be great.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!